# Conditional Where statement in Linq

Tags: c#, linq

My Linq statement gives an error.
Now the issue is that I'm at a project that uses a custom built datalayer, so I don't know wether I'm creating the wrong Linq statement or that the datalayer just can't handle it.

So here's the statement:

```
IQueryable<Affiliate> temp;

Func<RolePersonRole, bool> func;
if (roleMustBePrimary)
{
    func  = role => role.RolePersonRoleIsPrimary.Value == true;    
}
else
{
    func = role => role.RoleId == role.RoleId;

}
temp = (from affiliate in DataFacade.Instance().Tables(SessionTicket).Affiliates()
        join role in DataFacade.Instance().Tables(SessionTicket).RolePersonRoles().Where(func) on affiliate.PersonId
            equals role.PersonId
        where role.RoleId == roleId
                && affiliate.AffiliateAssuranceLevel == assuranceLevelEnum
        select affiliate);
```

The meaning is that if the bool `roleMustBePrimary` is true, a where statement should be added, and if it's false, it should not be added (hence the `role => role.RoleId == role.RoleId`).

The error I'm getting is:

> The expression of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[SkillsNG.Modules.RolePersons.Entities.RolePersonRole]'
>   is not a sequence

Comment: What if you move your Where(func) to your where clause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Wouter said, you do not need the `.Where()`, you can express it more clearly:

```
var temp = 
    from affiliate in DataFacade.Instance().Tables(SessionTicket).Affiliates()
    join role in 
        from r in DataFacade.Instance().Tables(SessionTicket).RolePersonRoles()
        where roleMustBePrimary && r.RolePersonRoleIsPrimary.Value 
              || !roleMustBePrimary
        select r
    on affiliate.PersonId equals role.PersonId
    where role.RoleId == roleId
          && affiliate.AffiliateAssuranceLevel == assuranceLevelEnum
    select affiliate;
```

Comment: One question though: is the `Where(func)` construction an unsupported construction?

Comment: It's supported, no problem with that, you are just mixing the 'query syntax' way with the 'fluent calls' way to express queries. Sometimes you cannot avoid it, but in this case it's possible, so for readability I think sticking with the query syntax it's better